# Dashboard menu missing

Tags: admin, admin-menu, dashboard

I've lost the `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables in a wordpress installation. I've recreated them and insert a new admin user. In particular, in `wpAA_users` (I use the prefix `wpAA_`), I have now a user `admin` with `ID=1`, while in `wpAA_usermeta`, for `user_id=1` I have `wp_cabilities` set to `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}` and `wp_user_level` set to `10`.

Now, when I log in to the site the top tool bar shows on the left the general wordpress menu, then the name of the user without the Dashboard menu, and on the right again the hello user name menu (here is a [link to the site](http://bianchimani.com)).

I looked at the `wpAA_user_role` option in the `wpAA_options` table, that contain a long string, starting with:

`a:5:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:71:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;s:16:"activate_plugins";b:1;s:12:"edit_plugins";b:1;s:10:"edit_users";...`

I do not know if the user that I've created is not really an administrator, or if something else horribly wrong happened.

So my question is: there is some error in the way used to create a new administrator, or at least how can I diagnose the problem?

Note: I have four or five plugins, and use theme Twenty Seventeen.

Comment: Looks OK to me at first glance. You could try using [wp cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/create/) to make an admin user too?

Comment: I've create another admin user directly in the database, but the result is the same. Note that I cannot open a shell on the wp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the names of the meta keys of the `wpAA_users` table: instead of using `wp_capabilities` and `wp_user_level` I should have used the actual prefix, that is `wpAA_capabilities` and `wpAA_user_level`.

With these modifications I can now access the site as administrator.